# Calculation of power for a pipeline crawler

Tags: mechanical-engineering, motors, power

I am an engineering student. I am working on a project where we need to use something called a vertical pipeline crawler. It is just a device that travels inside pipelines for inspection.

I found a crawler online, and I wanted to calculate the amount of power it uses. In specifications (there is more specs than below):
Speeds up to 10 m/min
Mass: 10 kg
Maximum pull: 27 kg
Power: 600 W 115 / 230 VAC

Initially what I did was to multiply the weight it can carry by the speed:
m*g*v = 27*9.81*(10/60) = 44.145 Watts
But it also says 600 W for power in specs. So how much power does this device need? Is the input 600 and output 44.145, isn't that very inefficient for an electrical device? Is my thought process wrong, what should use?

(I didn't want to share the link for the product thinking it might be against the website rules, however its pretty easy to find online)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question "power does this device need?" is unclear. If you are concerned about how much electrical power it requires, thats 600W and the current it requires will be given by dividing thus with the line voltage. The diameter of the electrical power cable will be determined by this.

When you multiply speed with the downward force you are neglecting how much energy the device has to expend in operating the gripping mechanism. In addition there is the electrical power requirement for the inspection head. You need to consider all of these.